# Exam class: best way to redefine \question command to apply custom formatting

Tags: macros, exam

EDIT: In summary the answer really turned out elegant and sipmle. Thanks to all the answers below!

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%...
\renewcommand\questionshook{\preto{\question}{\large\bfseries}}

% If we don't want the question's parts to be huge as well!
%\renewcommand\partshook{\normalsize\normalfont}
```

---

Shortly, I want to generate a custom exam sheet document class based on the [`exam` class](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam) to use in a group of colleagues. For the purpose, I want to redefine the default `\question` command to apply some custom formatting.

Suppose I want to make the default `\question` section large and bold. What I'm now doing is the following:

```
\newcommand\lquestion{\large\bfseries\question}
```

So, in order to use my custom formatting, I have to write the following in my documents instead:

```
\begin{lquestion}
A large and bold question: what is the mass of the sun?
\end{lquestion}
```

(I've read that using commands as environments is okay in LaTeX, but correct me if that hides some underwater stones.)

What would be the best way to redefine the `question` command, which comes from `exam.cls`, as an environment so that I don't have to prepend that bonus `l` at the beginning of the environment and can use the default contained name `question` instead?

EDIT:
A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{MWE}
\author{John Doe}
\date{November 2020}

%print solutions by default (for MWE's sake)
\printanswers
% do not put a box/frame around printed solutions
\unframedsolutions

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{questions}
    %this is basically what I want the result to look like:
    {\large\bfseries
        \question My large and bold question:
        \begin{parts}
        \part First part
        \part Second part
        \end{parts}
    }
    %but instead of this rather inconvenient form, I want to define an environment {question} with the same effect and use it like:
    %
    % \begin{question}
    % My large and bold question:
    % \begin{parts}
    %     \part First part
    %     \part Second part
    % \end{parts}
    % \end{question}
    
    
    \begin{solution}
    My general solution prerequisite.
    \begin{parts}
        \part My first part solution
        \part My second part solution
    \end{parts}
    \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The `\question`'s definition can be found on line 2845 in [`exam.cls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam) inside the `questions` environment:

```
\newenvironment{questions}{%
  %.... lots of code here
  \def\question{%
    \@bonusfalse
    \def\thequestiontitle{\csname p@question\endcsname
                          \csname thequestion\endcsname}%
    \process@question
  }%
  %.... lots of other code here
%and waaaaay down on line 3143
}% End of the second argument of \newenvironment{questions}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can simply use `{\large\bfseries \question My large and bold question:}`.  It has no effect on the rest of the code.  \question is implemented as an \item in a list, not an environment or macro with an argument.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's exactly what I was initially doing, but I wanted to shorten it and make this behaviour default, whilst also using `question` as an environment for a somewhat more obvious encapsulation of sections. Are there any downsides to what I've gone with as stated in my last edit?

Comment: The real question is what is it that needs to NOT be \large\bfseries?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well, initially I wanted the `parts` to also be formatted, then I saw your suggestion and thought that sometimes that'd be ugly, but now I can even smoothly choose between turning that on and off. So, I'm happy with the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've already found that you can use a command as an environment, so your question is really "how can I redefine the `question` command so that it has `\large\bfseries` at the beginning".  The problem that you've uncovered is that the `questions` environment defines the `\question` command.  In which case, I think your example works with

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\questions}{%
 \preto{\question}{\large\bfseries}%
 \printanswers%
}
```

I'm not happy with needing to have `\printanswers` in there, but the solutions disappear otherwise.  So you may be stuck needing to keep track of two different `\printanswers` commands.

As to the environment question: `\begin{myenv}...\end{myenv}` becomes `\begingroup\myenv ...\endmyenv\endgroup`, (where `\endmyenv` won't cause an error if it doesn't exist).  The upshot is that you automatically group your `\large\bfseries` so that it doesn't alter the rest of your document.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info! As I found out, `\question` is not actually a `\newcommand` from within the package, but rather a `\def\question` and so on... So with this code I get `LaTeX Error: Command \question undefined.`

Comment: It's not that it's def or newcommand.  The problem is that `\question` doesn't exist outside of the `questions` environment.

Comment: @D.Petrov I've updated my attempt.  I don't suppose you could edit an example into your original post that we could work with?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think of that! An example has been included for better understanding and playing around.
P.S. Your proposal failed with weird errors, but I'll leave the practical testing to you to see for yourself.

Comment: @D.Petrov I don't entirely understand it all, but I think I've gotten your example to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, prepending this also fails with various errors. Can you maybe also include a MWE of your attempt that's working for you? And maybe it's worth mentioning that I'm using Overleaf as an online redactor with pdfLaTeX as compiler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116121/discussion-between-d-petrov-and-teepeemm).

Comment: You code was literally almost right! I dug deeper into the mechanics of the whole process and it turned out that the inner statement should simply be `\preto{\question}{\large\bfseries}`. I'm not really sure why exactly it works like this, but as far as I can explain it to myself, we're prepending to `\question` after the expansion of its use as an environment, so a simple `\preto` does the trick and doesn't even interfere with the parameters! Just update your answer and I will accept it!

Comment: And when implemented in my actual project, outside of the MWE, the outer `\apptocmd` also seems to be better off being just `\appto`. I can't currently explain why and would be glad to gain some deeper understanding.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to enlighten you about why it ended up working the way it did.

Comment: One last thing: for me the MWE worked also without defining `\printanswers` inside of the `\appto`, so I guess you can check that one out as well. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Actually, one can use `\questionshook`, `\partshook` and `\SolutionEmphasis` to handle formatting changes.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{MWE}
\author{John Doe}
\date{November 2020}

%print solutions by default (for MWE's sake)
\printanswers
% do not put a box/frame around printed solutions
\unframedsolutions

\renewcommand\questionshook{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\partshook{\normalsize\normalfont}
\SolutionEmphasis{\normalsize\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{questions}
     \question %\begingroup ... \endgroup not needed
     My large and bold question:
     \begin{parts}
         \part First part
         \part Second part
     \end{parts}
    
    \begin{solution}
    My general solution prerequisite.
    \begin{parts}
        \part My first part solution
        \part My second part solution
    \end{parts}
    \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So I took the time to read almost all of `etoolbox`'s documentation, but didn't really think of checking for hooks in the `exam` documentation... Really helpful insight and elegant solution! Thank you! The only problem is that it affects my document outside the 'question' environment as well, more precisely it makes my `solutions` main part (before the `parts` initiation) also large and bold. You can see my post edited with the options for a solution.

Comment: It doesn't leak, it just applies to everything in the questions or parts environments.  There is also a fix for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to create an environment is using `\newenvironment{<name>}{<begin code>}{<end code>}`. So in your case, this would just be `\newenvironment{\lquestion}{\large\bfseries\question}{}` You could add anything else that you like into the begin or end code. The begin code is what happens at `\begin{lquestion}` tag and the end code is what happens at the `\end{lquestion}` tag. There are more advanced ways to do this of course but this is the most simple method and there is no need for something more complex in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm familiar with that. The problem is I want my environment to be called `question`, but that name is already in use and the compilation throws a bunch of errors...

Comment: @D. Petrov My apologies. I've seen the issue that you had with the other solution as well. I believe that the other solution would likely work if you replaced `\renewcommand` with `\def` or perhaps one of the versions of that like `\xdef`.

Comment: I really tried to play around with that, but the problem is that the `\question`'s management inside of `exam.cls` is somewhat more complex and I really can't cope with redefining it. So I guess the question narrows itself down to: can one define an environment with an already `\def`'d name, just like in this case?